# Localize Plugin Description

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

Currently i'm working on a simple WordPress Plugin.

I know within the Plugin i need to write my strings as `__()` or `_e()` and call `load_plugin_textdomain()` but i wonder how to localize the Plugin Description.

Example:
[image: example]

*This is not the Plugin i'm working on. It's just an example to show what i mean.*

Comment: Plugin description is in comment block and I think it can't be localized

Comment: I know it's a comment block thats why i ask :) Plugin URI and Author URI are parsed as link. It should be possible to translate. Makes sense imho...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add two extra headers:

```
Text Domain: your-text-domain
Domain Path: /languages
```

Then use the [plugin Codestyling Localization](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/codestyling-localization/) to create your language files. Usually it'll find the description.

Comment: It's not exactly what i want if i understand you correctly. Localization is not the problem, i'm using Poedit.

As i can read the Plugin only reads gettext components. But i'm not sure the Plugin-Description is a gettext component.

Comment: It is what you want – if you use the Codestyling plugin instead of Poedit. You could hack around Poedit’s restriction by inserting a dummy string with the content of your description somewhere.

Comment: Ok, but every user who installed my plugin needs to install the Codestyling Localization Plugin too, isn't it?

Comment: No, this plugin is needed to *create* the language files only.